# How to find the order of elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having trouble finding the order of the elements of the groups $D_{9}$ and $S_{3}$ x $Z_{3}$. I was wondering how would I go about this? I know the order of an element $g$ in $G$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ : $g^{n}$ = $e$. However that makes sense to me if we are dealing with groups in modulo. What would the order of the elements be for the groups above? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just take $g$ and keep multiplying it by itself.  You'll see when you arrive at $e$.

Comment: @david Thanks! I constructed a cayley table for $D_{9}$ and saw that $R$ $R^{8}$ gives me $e$. How can I use this information to get the order of $R$ or $R^{8}$?

Comment: You answer your own comment question in your posting, above.

Comment: So $R^9=e$ and the order of $R$ is $9$

Comment: That makes sense! How would i do this process for $S_{3}$ x $Z_{3}$? Sorry if this question seems dumb.

Answer (score 1):

In $D_9$ there are $9$ rotations and $9$ reflections.  Picture a regular $9$-gon, and its symmetries.  The rotations form a cyclic group of order $9$.  Hence there are  $\varphi(d)$ rotations of order $d$ for every $d$ dividing $9$.  The reflections all have order $2$.

For the second one, the order of an element $(a,b)$ in the product is $\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.  Now $S_3$ is actually $D_3$, the symmetries of an equilateral triangle.  The other factor is the cyclic group of order $3$.